# Why is the same value being return in this SQL While Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am using Microsoft SQL Server, and attempting to insert some data into a temporary table. I then want to use a while loop to loop through each row in the temporary table. I do no want to use a cursor.

Please see the query below:

```
-- Create Table

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TMP_ABC

CREATE TABLE #TMP_ABC

(
  [ABC] [varchar](3) NULL,
)
 
-- Insert Values
INSERT INTO [#TMP_ABC] VALUES ('AAA')
INSERT INTO [#TMP_ABC] VALUES ('BBB')
INSERT INTO [#TMP_ABC] VALUES ('CCC')
INSERT INTO [#TMP_ABC] VALUES ('DDD')
INSERT INTO [#TMP_ABC] VALUES ('EEE')
INSERT INTO [#TMP_ABC] VALUES ('FFF')
 
-- Display values

DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @row INT
SET @row = 1;

DECLARE @ABC varchar(3)

SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(ABC) FROM #TMP_ABC)

WHILE (@row <= @count) BEGIN
    SELECT @ABC = ABC FROM #TMP_ABC
    PRINT @ABC
    SET @row += 1
END
```

Here is what is returned from the query:

```
(1 row affected)
FFF
FFF
FFF
FFF
FFF
FFF
```

I was hoping for the following to be returned instead:

```
(1 row affected)
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

Please can somebody 'kindly' show me the error in my ways, and how to achieve this?

Comment: Because SQL Server doesn't have any clue that you expect it to know your `@row` variable relates to a row in the temp table.

Comment: To loop over rows in a table, use a cursor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why do you want to loop in the first place? SQL is a set based language; the *last* thing you should be doing is looping. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: `I do no want to use a cursor.` WHY? This is what a cursor is for (assuming, once more, that you have a legitimate need to loop in the first place). Has someone misinformed you that a while loop is better than (or is not) a cursor?

Comment: *"I do no want to use a cursor."*  You already are. If you don't want the *loop* you need to ask a new question and explain your real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue happens because SQL Server doesn't associate `@row` with a row in the table (the correlation is obvious to you, but SQL Server isn't human).

As you loop through the numbers `1 -> @count`, it is running the same `SELECT @ABC = ABC FROM #TMP_ABC` over and over again. There is no `WHERE` clause and no `TOP` so SQL Server is just reading the whole table every time, and setting the variable equal to the last `ABC` value it read.

Instead, you should use a cursor (if you need to loop at all; usually you don't, per [@Larnu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790839/ssms-why-is-the-same-value-being-return-in-this-sql-while-loop/70790897#comment125147445_70790839)). You have have read some misinformation somewhere that cursors are bad and that while loops are not cursors, but these are both false.

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Thinking a WHILE loop isn't a CURSOR](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)
- [What impact can different cursor options have?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)
- [Follow-up on cursor options](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options-2)
- [Overlooked T-SQL Gems](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/10/t-sql-queries/overlooked-t-sql-gems#cursor) (see why using a local variable for a cursor is even better than the regular type you probably use)

If you do in fact need to loop for some reason, here's a rewrite:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_ABC(ABC varchar(3));

INSERT INTO #TMP_ABC(ABC) VALUES 
  ('AAA'),('BBB'),('CCC'),('DDD'),('EEE'),('FFF');
  
DECLARE @ABC varchar(3), @c cursor;
    
SET @c = cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT ABC FROM #TMP_ABC;

OPEN @c;
FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @ABC;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  PRINT @ABC;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @ABC;
END
```

Output:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3289329b99d10aca86111bfe9fd8cf6)

But I'm not sure what that accomplishes over `SELECT ABC FROM #TMP_ABC;`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Aaron Bertrand, yes I've heard they are bad for performance on large datasets.

Comment: @LloydThomas So are WHILE loops. You have a #temp table with 6 rows. If you get bigger and/or real tables, and you really do need to loop over large resultsets one painful row at a time, yes a cursor is still the way to do it. Just use the right options in that case.

Comment: I wouldn't tend to put a large dataset on Stack Overflow, the six rows was just an example. Okay, thanks for your input.

Comment: @LloydThomas Your (next?) question should probably be "how do I do {this thing you haven't explained is _behind_ this problem} _without a cursor **or** a while loop_? You could probably solve this specific problem with a while loop but it would either be really convoluted or you would require a schema change (like the column is unique or there is another way to uniquely identify / apply a row number to each row, like an identity column).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 1):

use ROW_NUMBER() function and pass the value through a variable in WHERE clause in the loop.

```
--Create another Temp table
CREATE table #Tem_abc (r int , abc varchar(3));

--Add Row number

insert into #Tem_abc
select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by ABC) as r,*
from #TMP_ABC;

--Use the loop
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @row INT;
SET @row = 1;
DECLARE @ABC varchar(3);
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(ABC) FROM #TMP_ABC);
--SET @count = (SELECT max(r) FROM #Tem_abc);

WHILE (@row <= @count) BEGIN
    
    SELECT @ABC = ABC FROM #Tem_abc where @row = r;
     PRINT @ABC;
    SET @row += 1;
END
```