# t-sql process large set of SQL rows without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I need to loop through 16 million rows of SQL data. I have been told not to use a cursor for this because of performance issues. I have started with a WHILE loop but I can't figure out how to get the next row in the table using a WHILE loop. See my progress below. How do I get the AccountNames column for each row?

```
DECLARE @rowId INT = 1;
DECLARE @RowCnt BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @source varchar(8000);
DECLARE @current_source varchar(8000);
DECLARE @search varchar(8000) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
DECLARE @replacement varchar(8000) = '22233344455566677778889999';
DECLARE @Converted varchar(8000) ;

SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(0) FROM dbo.AccountNames;
select @source = AccountNumber FROM dbo.AccountNames where AccountNumber > ' ' order by Accountnumber;

WHILE @rowId <= 2
BEGIN

declare @i int, @iMax int;
set @iMax = len(@search);
set @i = 1;
while @i <= @iMax
begin
    set @Converted = replace(@source, substring(@search, @i, 1), substring(@replacement, @i, 1));
    set @i = @i + 1;
end

select @source = AccountNumber FROM dbo.AccountNames where AccountNumber > @current_source order by Accountnumber ;
print @source;
set @current_source = @source;
Set @rowId = @rowId + 1;
END
```

-edit
Thanks for the super fast comments. I will provide more detail based on the requests in the comments section.

I need to take the AccountNumber field from each record in AccountNames, convert it to the keypad value shown in my code, then insert that value into a different table that holds the AccountNumber and its Keypad equivalent. If cursors are OK for a table this large then I would appreciate someone showing me the proper syntax for that.

-edit 2
I can't use translate because I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: You likely don't need a loop at all.  What is your end goal here?  Add sample data and desired results and we can probably help you to avoid the loop altogether.  Whenever the thought "I need a loop" comes to your mind in t-sql it's a high likelihood that you're being lied to...

Comment: I'd say a while loop is even worse. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Whoever told you a while loop is faster than a cursor is misinformed IMHO. (More info in [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor) and [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70790897/61305).)

Comment: Still not sure I understand why you need to handle one row at a time, and it's certainly hard to see what you're doing when your sample code just prints the output.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't use either a cursor *or* a while loop.

Comment: Using cursors or WHILE loops, also known as RBAR - that's Row By Agonising Row!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the "Translate" answer is obviously the more elegant solution, if you can't use it because of version compatibility you could replace it with nested REPLACE statements. It should still run much faster than a cursor or a while loop, and the results can be used in set operations like INSERT. I tested this on SQL 2014 and it worked, so 2016 should give you no problems

```
with cteSampleData as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('CXE-34-A5'), ('52Q-A6-brxt'), ('kqed-pc-12ALE')
         ) as Accts(AccountNumber)
), cteTranslated as ( 
 SELECT AccountNumber
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(AccountNumber, 
         'A', '2'), 'B', '2'), 'C', '2'), 
         'D', '3'), 'E', '3'), 'F', '3'), 
         'G', '4'), 'H', '4'), 'I', '4'), 
         'J', '5'), 'K', '5'), 'L', '5'), 
         'M', '6'), 'N', '6'), 'O', '6'), 
         'P', '7'), 'Q', '7'), 'R', '7'), 'S', '7'), 
         'T', '8'), 'U', '8'), 'V', '8'), 
         'W', '9'), 'X', '9'), 'Y', '9'), 'Z', '9'
      ) as AcctTrans
 FROM cteSampleData
) --INSERT INTO DestTable (RawAcct, TranslatedAcct) 
SELECT AccountNumber, AcctTrans
FROM cteTranslated
```

EDIT: The output looks like this:

| AccountNumber | AcctTrans |
| --- | --- |
| CXE-34-A5 | 293-34-25 |
| 52Q-A6-brxt | 527-26-2798 |
| kqed-pc-12ALE | 5733-72-12253 |

Comment: I was going to try this because this was the answer in other web sites. You confirmed the efficiency for me so I will  use it. Thanks!

Comment: Very nice. I was going to post a version using a function, but this is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this whole thing with one SELECT statement:

```
DECLARE @search varchar(8000) =      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
DECLARE @replacement varchar(8000) = '2223334445556667777888999922233344455566677778889999';

SELECT  AccountNumber,
        TRANSLATE(AccountNumber, @search, @replacement) AS TranslatedAcctNum
FROM    dbo.AccountNames 
WHERE   Accountnumber > 'DDDDDD' 
order by AccountNumber;
```

Which can also be easily turned into a single INSERT statement.

As an added benefit, it will run 10-1000 times faster.

*(Note: Without any test data, I could not test it, so there may be typos, but they should be easily fixable.)*

Comment: I can't use translate because i am on an SQL version 2016.

Comment: @WorkJ  This is information that you should have included in your original question, so that others do not spend time developing a solution that you cannot use.

Comment: I am a beginner and did not know about the 2016 constraint until i tried your solution. I got an error message and googled the message. That is how I found out I can't  use your solution (which i would have if I could).

Answer (score -3):

I found a way to do it with a cursor. Instead of printing the account number, I will put an  insert statement into the final version of this code.

```
DECLARE @rowId INT = 1;
DECLARE @AccountNum varchar(8000);
DECLARE @c cursor;
DECLARE @search varchar(8000) =      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
DECLARE @replacement varchar(8000) = '2223334445556667777888999922233344455566677778889999';
DECLARE @Converted varchar(8000) ;


SET @c = cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT AccountNumber 
FROM dbo.AccountNames 
where Accountnumber > 'DDDDDD' 
order by AccountNumber;

OPEN @c;
fetch next from @c into @AccountNum;

While @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    print @AccountNum;
    declare @i int, @iMax int;
    set @iMax = len(@search);
    set @i = 1;
    while @i <= @iMax
    begin
        set @AccountNum = replace(@AccountNum, substring(@search, @i, 1), substring(@replacement, @i, 1));
        set @i = @i + 1;
    end

    print @AccountNum; --put insert statement here
    fetch next from @c into @AccountNum;

    set @rowId = @rowId + 1; --remove this test code after code is finished
    if @rowId > 1
    begin
        break
    end

END

close @c;
deallocate @c;
```

Comment: How many hours does it take for this to run?

Comment: If you go with a cursor, you'll also need a transation.  Otherwise the log is flushed after each INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement..

Comment: David Brown - What do you mean i will need a tranlsation? Btw, I am using SQL 2016